# List of natural numbers in coq

Tags: coq

I am writing a lemma about the length of natlist(l) , statement of the lemma is "length of l equal to zero gives false"  (length l=?0)=false. This is only possible when list have head, head and tail or empty /[] list never appears.Please help me in writing this statement in Proposition. _ ->(length l=?0)=false.

Answer (score 2):

What about `forall l : natlist, l <> [] -> (length l =? 0) = false`?